# How to use one controller for more than one sql query in Cakephp?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have a serious deadlock about my project. I am looking for a solution for days but there is nothing.

My index page have 4 different mysql queries. I tried to code this at first inside 1 controller and 1 view. It was not the right way. Then somebody suggested using 4 elements with requestAction() function. It was very good at first. Then I needed mysql between command. I could not found a way for it to use with requestAction(). My question on Cakephp group still unanswered. Somebody suggested using actions in controller. But I couldn't figure it out how to create that controller.

Please tell me what you know about it. Thanks in advance,

Here is my current post controller's index function:

```
function index() {
        $posts = $this->paginate();
        if (isset($this->params['requested'])) {
            return $posts;
        } else {
            $sql = array( 'conditions' => array( 'id BETWEEN ? AND ?' => array( 286, 291 ) ) );
            $this->Post->find('all', $sql);
            $this->set('posts', $posts);
        }
}
```

What should I do? Should I add a new controller for rest 3 actions? Or should I do something inside index() function?

Comment: Could you back up a bit and tell us what kind of 4 different queries you need in which circumstance and where these queries are going to be used?

Comment: Course I do. Thank you.

Here is my project. http://bake.yemeklog.com/

I want to put that 3 columns. One for lates posts. One for top rated last 10 days. One for top rated last 30 days. That's OK to code last  posts and top rated all time via elements. But when I need mysql between command, everything stops there. Is it clear?

Comment: Your comment reminds me of this blog post: http://teknoid.wordpress.com/2008/12/16/how-to-build-a-dashboard-for-your-application-in-cakephp/

Comment: Hey deizel, thank you very much. It seems finally I found what I look for. Article may be improved a little bit more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time I need several queries in the single controller I do this way:

```
// model Foo
function edit($id){
    $this->data = $this->Foo->read(null, $id);
    $second = $this->Foo->Foo2->find('list');
    $third = $this->Foo->Foo3->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('second', 'third')); 
}
```

I guess, you want to paginate on those 3 columns so the example above is not good for that.

I think you have an error in your method. `$posts` is not related to your `find`. There should be `$posts = $this->Post->find('all', $sql);`. But this would not allow you to paginate on the result. Take a look at [Custom Query Pagination](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1237/Custom-Query-Pagination) in the manual. Maybe this would work for you:

```
function index(){
    if(!isset($this->params['requested'])) {
        $this->paginate = array('Post' => array(
            'conditions' => array('id BETWEEN ? AND ?' => array(286, 291))
        ));
    }
    $this->set('posts', $this->paginate());
}
```